# Redirect using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

Currently, my website works with `www` and without `www`, i.e:

`http://oshirowanen.com` and `http://www.oshirowanen.com`

However, I seem to be getting penalised for SEO purposes for duplications. Is it possible to redirect all web page urls when they do not have the www to the equivalent www version of the web page?

For example

```
http://oshirowanen.com should go to http://www.oshirowanen.com
http://oshirowanen.com/page1 should go to http://www.oshirowanen.com/page1
http://oshirowanen.com/page2 should go to http://www.oshirowanen.com/page2
http://oshirowanen.com/page3 should go to http://www.oshirowanen.com/page3
```

and so on?

Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible - add the following to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Am I supposed to restart apache after adding this to `.htaccess`?  I've not restarted, and `http://oshirowanen.com` does not go to `http://www.oshirowanen.com`.

Comment: Please see update above original question.

Comment: You need to refresh the root, not restart apache

Comment: How do you refresh the root?  I don't know what that means.

Comment: I move those 2 lines to the top of the `.htaccess` file and it's now working.  Thanks.